# Выбор данных для обучения нейронных сетей

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Как я могу изменить эту нейронную сеть, чтобы я мог загрузить свои данные в нее. Я не могу определиться с выбором моих данных для обучения. Я использую Google Colab. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EsFddgNPExMs1dVW4Z4A_HhhTG2AlIkF

Я научился загружать свои данные в Google Colab, но не могу разобраться как описать каталог и данные для обучения сети и проверки качества обучения. Мне нужно именно обучить сеть с нуля, а не дообучать уже готовую нейронную сеть. Напишите, пожалуйста, универсальный код, который я смогу модифицировать под свои классы.

Я прошу помощи, так как я честно сижу с этим не первый день и все еще не смог разобраться с этой проблемой, хотя понимаю что проблема-то плевая.

Если нужно, то вот данные которые я использую для тестового обучения сети: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ev2KbwcCo-h_feIZDUS53q7QnalO9QMk/view?usp=sharing

Как я загружаю их в Google Colab: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p7f41Ucth7p-mx6wBLSPETI7l87FgYqh

Comment: пофиксил ссылки

Comment: Так а что вы хотите за задачу то решить? Нет универсального кода, когда дело касается мл. Вам в любой случае надо настраивать архитектуру, пороговую функцию, способ оптимизации и т.д.

Comment: @vladimir-afanasyev, мне нужно разработать нейронную сеть для классификации изображений. Я собираюсь использовать модель которую использует гугл в демонстрационном туториале TensorFlow в котором они обучили сеть классифицировать предметы одежды. В этом туториале они обозначают данные одной строчкой: `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()`. Мне нужно подставить свои данные в эту сеть и обучить ее с нуля. Т.е. обозначить x_train и y_train. Честное слово, не могу разобраться с этим. Фигня-фигней, но все равно не понимаю. Это очень грустно.